# Bash Script to Check Port Availability with Timestamp

Tags: bash, scripting, osx-yosemite, netcat

Using netcat, on Mac OS X 10.10, I would like to test every minute for listening ports on a Facilis TerraBlock server, to confirm the ethernet listener is functioning.

I would like the script to output one line for success and one line for failure, and have a preceding line logging the date/timestamp. I don't presently need to have any of this logged to a file.

Something like these native nectat outputs would be ideal:

```
Wed Feb  4 10:49:09 EST 2015
Connection to 10.40.255.11 port 859 [tcp/*] succeeded!
nc: connectx to 10.40.255.12 port 859 (tcp) failed: Connection refused
```

This is the script I've created:

```
#!/bin/bash

date
nc -z 10.40.255.11 859 || nc -vz 10.40.255.11 859
nc -z 10.40.255.12 859 || nc -vz 10.40.255.12 859

while sleep 60; do date;nc -z 10.40.255.11 859 || nc -vz 10.40.255.11 859 & nc -z 10.40.255.12 859 || nc -vz 10.40.255.12 859; done
```

This script is behaving unpredictably and I surmise it's the || operator, but I cannot find another way to do this well. Specifically, when the script runs the terminal output alternates between the .11 and .12 tests being first or second after the timestamp, which leads me to wonder if it's simply a connection timeout for the netcat response that's causing the replies to be occasionally out of order, or if there's a greater problem and my script is returning unreliable data.

Here's an example of my current output:

```
Fri Feb  6 10:51:33 EST 2015
Connection to 10.40.255.11 port 859 [tcp/*] succeeded!
Connection to 10.40.255.12 port 859 [tcp/*] succeeded!
Fri Feb  6 10:51:34 EST 2015
Connection to 10.40.255.12 port 859 [tcp/*] succeeded!
Connection to 10.40.255.11 port 859 [tcp/*] succeeded!
Fri Feb  6 10:51:35 EST 2015
Connection to 10.40.255.12 port 859 [tcp/*] succeeded!
Connection to 10.40.255.11 port 859 [tcp/*] succeeded!
Fri Feb  6 10:51:36 EST 2015
Connection to 10.40.255.11 port 859 [tcp/*] succeeded!
Connection to 10.40.255.12 port 859 [tcp/*] succeeded!
```

I added the || and & operators, and the seemingly redundant code because I only want to see verbose output of netcat if the connection fails.

Comment: what happens in you remove the `&` in your while loop? This evaluations will have less "flexibility", and you should get a more ordered listing. Also, it might help to edit  your question and include your preferred output, as well as the current output you are getting. Good luck.

Comment: shelter, if I remove the & operator the script will only query the .11 address. I've added the current output. Thank you.

Comment: Ha, 1 more `&` not one less;-).  (my fault). .... `nc ...11 ||  nc ...11 && nc ...12 || nc ....12` should force evaluation for at least 1 .11 addr and 1. 12 addr? Does that help? Good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your script could be more reliable as below:

```
#! /bin/bash

ips="10.40.255.11 10.40.255.11 10.40.255.12 10.40.255.12"

while  true ; do
  # This will make sure it will run every 60 seconds, not 60 seconds + whatever nc takes to execute
  sleep 60 & 
  date
  for ip in $ips; do
    # Note that we're using -w to timeout 
    out=$(nc -zvw 2 $ip 859 2>&1) && echo "$out" && break
  done || echo "$out"
  # This waits for sleep in background 
  wait
done
```

Comment: Tiago, very nicely laid out. When running, your script appears to only test the .11 address. Maybe there's something with the break that's causing it to skip the remaining addresses in the ips list...

Comment: I misunderstood your requirement then, can you show your desired output?